# No content in javaFX tableview

Tags: javafx, dynamic, groovy, load, tableview

So I checked the other [No content in TableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25822937/no-content-in-tableview) but it was no help.

I have a database named ledger and I want to bring my transactions into view.

```
void buildData(){

    final ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> data = null

    try{
        //ResultSet
        ResultSet rs = sql.getTransactions(account.getValue().toString())

        /**********************************
         * TABLE COLUMN ADDED DYNAMICALLY *
         **********************************/
        for(int i=0 ; i<rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){
            //We are using non property style for making dynamic table
            final int j = i
            TableColumn col = new TableColumn(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i+1))
            col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList,String>,ObservableValue<String>>(){
                ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {
                    return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString())
                }
            })

            budgetTable.getColumns().addAll(col)
        }

        /********************************
         * Data added to ObservableList *
         ********************************/
        while(rs.next()){
            //Iterate Row

            ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList()
            for(int i=1 ; i<=rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){
                //Iterate Column
                row.add(rs.getString(i))
            }
            println("Row [1] added "+row )
            data?.add(row)
        }

        //FINALLY ADDED TO TableView
        budgetTable.setItems(data)
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace()
        System.out.println("Error on Building Data")
    }
}
```

I have 5 columns in the database that do comeback and are added to the tableview.  These are date, from_account, to_account, amount & notes:

```
mysql> show columns from ledger;
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | bigint(20)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| version      | bigint(20)  | NO   |     | 1       |                |
| date         | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| notes        | varchar(35) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| amount       | double      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| from_account | varchar(19) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| to_account   | varchar(55) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.45 sec)
```

I get no error or otherwise I would have a very good chance of solving it.  At this point I don't know what the problem is.  Just says "No content in table" upon build.  The file is a groovy file so that's why it looks like python syntax.

Thank you in advance for your help, time and insights!
Be well!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with Groovy but I believe I know what the issue is. First off, you declare `data` as `final` and then assign `null` to it.

```
final ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> data = null;
```

This means it will be `null` when to go to set the items of the `TableView`. Basically, you're calling `budgetTable.setItems(null)`. You would not normally reach this point because calling `data.add(row)` would throw a `NullPointerException`; except you don't use `data.add(row)` but rather `data?.add(row)`. The `?` here is the [safe navigation operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_safe_navigation_operator).

> The Safe Navigation operator is used to avoid a `NullPointerException`. Typically when you have a reference to an object you might need to verify that it is not `null` before accessing methods or properties of the object. To avoid this, the safe navigation operator will simply return `null` instead of throwing an exception...

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24186387/what-is-the-purpose-of-question-mark-after-a-variable-in-groovy) for more.

Given all this, simply changing:

```
final ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> data = null;
```

To:

```
final ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

Should solve your problem.

Comment: Indeed that was the issue!  Thank you so much.  Amazing that I looked over that code a number of times and never noticed.  I had to use the null safe operator bc I was given a null pointer exception and now I know why!